# Copy files from local directory to docker container on a remote host

Tags: bash, docker, ssh

I want to create a watcher that will automatically sync file changes from a local directory to a remote docker container. I need to find a way to transfer the files efficiently. I will also need it for a one time upload command which would transfer a complete folder from local directory to a remote docker container.

I figure one solution would be to scp to a tmp directory on the remote host, and then run docker cp via ssh to copy the files from tmp directory. Is that a good solution? Is there anything better?

By the way, if anyone knows a file sync utility for that use case, please let me know. I tried to search, but it seems like it's not the most popular development workflow?

Comment: Depending on your container you can use `scp` direct inside your container without the step over your remote system. But by now I have no better idea as `scp` ...

Comment: You generally do not directly interact with container filesystems.  Use some program like `rsync` to do the file copy host-to-host, and mount the target host directory into the container.

Answer (score 0):

I would tr using `rsync` for local to remote host syncing. From their volume mount the directory into the docker container.